# The symbol $\gtrsim$ versus $\ge$ in physics

Tags: notation

Currently I am going through [Thermodynamic cost of computation, algorithmic complexity and the information metric](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v341/n6238/abs/341119a0.html) by W. H. Zurek. In the introduction, he mentioned a relationship between the change in entropy and the difference between the length of a program and its output. It is as follows:

$$\delta S (i \to o) \gtrsim |i^*| - |o^*| $$

From the $\LaTeX$ code `\gtrsim`, I realize that $\gtrsim$ means 'greater or similar'. My question is how is it different from $\ge$?

Comment: "strictly greater than or equal to" vs "greater or nearly equal to" ?

Comment: Is this physics? Seems to me it is about the interpretation of a symbol.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's not going to be a rigorous definition; this is how I would read it as a working physicist. Usually $\sim$ means "of about the same size," often in an order of magnitude sense. So if we say $v \sim 1$ in means that $v$ might be like, 5. But probably $v < 10$. This kind of symbol would often appear in a calculation in which I chose not to keep track of certain things--for instance, if I'm interested in whether a relation is linear or quadratic, I don't care much about prefactors.

Which is all to say: I would read the equation you wrote as saying that the LHS is greater than something of similar size to the right hand side. So it might not be greater than, say, $10^9 \left( |i| - |o| \right)$ but the idea is that there's probably some constant attached to the front that isn't important for the relation being stated, and the method we used to calculate it might not give a reliable answer for that constant.

Comment: Just to add another example: I've used that symbol few days ago in a special relativity tutorial and wrote down $c \lesssim 3\cdot 10^{8} \frac{\textrm{m}}{\textrm{s}}$ when calculating space-time distances of event pairs. This means that for simplicity I'm using an approximate value for the speed of light, but have to keep in mind that the real value is a bit smaller than that. That is important when comparing lightlike to spacelike distances etc.